# Cassandra Reaper startup issue after first install in Centos

Tags: database, cassandra, reaper

Cassandra Reaper startup issue after first install in Centos

Configuration is proper in yml file.

cassandra:
  clusterName: "test"
  contactPoints: ["127.0.0.1"]
  keyspace: reaper_db

cassandra-reaper.err

find: './boot/efi': Permission denied
find: './boot/grub2': Permission denied
find: './proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
find: './proc/1/task/1/fd': Permission denied
find: './proc/1/task/1/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: './proc/1/task/1/ns': Permission denied
find: './proc/1/fd': Permission denied
find: './proc/1/map_files': Permission denied
find: './proc/1/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: './proc/1/ns': Permission denied
find: './proc/2/task/2/fd': Permission denied
find: './proc/2/task/2/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: './proc/2/task/2/ns': Permission denied
find: './proc/2/fd': Permission denied
find: './proc/2/map_files': Permission denied
find: './proc/2/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: './proc/2/ns': Permission denied
find: './proc/3/task/3/fd': Permission denied
find: './proc/3/task/3/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: './proc/3/task/3/ns': Permission denied
find: './proc/3/fd': Permission denied
find: './proc/3/map_files': Permission denied
find: './proc/3/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: './proc/3/ns': Permission denied
find: './proc/5/task/5/fd': Permission denied
find: './proc/5/task/5/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: './proc/5/task/5/ns': Permission denied
find: './proc/5/fd': Permission denied
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
at com.datastax.driver.core.InboundTrafficMeter.channelRead(InboundTrafficMeter.java:38)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:934)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:397)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:302)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

Answer (score 0):

From the above error:-

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

You need to check your Cassandra nodes whether all are UP and running cause it must meet the consistency level.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by updating data center name in keyspace. but now seeing below error.

Comment: org.cognitor.cassandra.migration.MigrationException: Error during migration of script 005_repair_specific_nodes.cql while executing 'ALTER TABLE repair_unit_v1 ADD nodes set<text>;'
        
  
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid column name nodes because it conflicts with an existing column

Comment: @user3262968 I'm confused as-to why you're commenting on someone else's post but the issue you're seeing is because of a schema mismatch. Did you update `cassandra-reaper` aswell? Reaper is complaning that needed columns are missing from one of the tables in the `cassandra-reaper` keyspace.